# IBM MobileFirst runtime environment creation using Linux command shell

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Environment :

```
IBM MobileFirst 7.1
IBM DB2
IBM WAS 8.5.5
OS : RHEL 7.1
```

I need to upload war project files and create runtime environment on the MF using Linux command shell (Putty) as I can't remote desktop the Linux server (BTW, is there any way to remote? I tried X11 but no success.)

Can you share the steps with commands to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

IBM MobileFirst Platform provides both a tool and Ant tasks to upload .war files to your production environment.

See the documentation here: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/deploy/c_deploy_wl_project.html